# Navegador por defecto no muestra index.xhtml al lanzar wildfly 18.0.1 con proyecto Maven en Eclipse sobre Linux

Tags: maven, wildfly

Estoy aprendiendo JEE, e intentando correr un proyecto Maven en un servidor wildfly  18.0.1 que he agregado al IDE Eclipse, todo ello sobre un sistema operativo Linux Ubuntu  Mate 20.04.

El servidor arranca correctamente, creo, pero el navegador por defecto de Eclipse,
mi Firefox, arroja el código de estado
***"Archivo no encontrado

Firefox no puede encontrar el archivo en /home/tecnicomanotas/http:/localhost:8081/vid_24_Web_Project_Maven/faces/index.xhtml."***

Y en la caja de direcciones de mi navegador aparece:
***file:///home/tecnicomanotas/http:/localhost:8081/vid_24_Web_Project_Maven/faces/index.xhtml***
Si elimino la primera parte de la ruta ***"file:///home/tecnicomanotas"*** funciona, y me muestra el fichero requerido.

En cambio, si elijo cualquier opción de navegador en Eclipse que no sea el navegador por defecto, al ejecutar el proyecto Maven sobre el servidor wildfly, el navegador me muestra el fichero index.xhtml  ***"Window/Web Browser/"***:

- 0 Internal Web Browser
- 2 Firefox
- 3 Chrome

He mirado el archivo de configuración **standalone.xml**, intentando encontrar la
manera de establecer esa ruta en la petición, pero no he encontrado, o no he sabido reconocer la parte donde se hace.

Estuve mirando el **web context** en el *server.log*, pero no saqué nada en claro.

La duda es ***¿còmo puedo establecer esa ruta para que también me funcione con

el navegador por defecto en Eclipse?***.

Por si alguien duda, los puertos por defecto han sido cambiados (8080 por 8081 y 9990 por 9991).

Si alguien tiene algún aporte con respecto a la pregunta y a como la he realizado, estaré encantado de leer las posibles mejoras.
Gracias a toda la comunidad por anticipado.